# How to access cookies correctly in express application

Tags: reactjs, express, cookies, jwt, mern

I have been having trouble on my MERN application I'm building. I am storing a token in cookies when I register/login a user. I am able to access this cookie through my express app fine and when using Postman all works as well.

Now the issue that I am encountering is when I try to access protected routes through my client side that is in React. I'm not sure how to handle this correctly because in my express app I can't get the cookie in the same matter I am doing so when using postman for example. I am using `httpOnly: true` so that the cookie can only be access from my express app. I want to keep this the way it is with `httpOnly` for security reasons so I do not want access to the token through my client side.

Here is my code on the express app...

```
exports.protect = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
  let token;

  if (
    req.headers.authorization &&
    req.headers.authorization.startsWith('Bearer')
  ) {
    token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
  }

  console.log(req.headers);

  if (!token) {
    return next(new AppError('No token found!', 401));
  }

  const decoded = await promisify(jwt.verify)(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
  const freshUser = await User.findById(decoded.id);

  if (!freshUser) {
    return res.status(401).json({
      status: 'fail',
      message: 'This token no longer exists!',
    });
  }

  req.user = freshUser;
  next();
});
```

When I try to access the token using `req.headers.authorization` using postman it works but like I mentioned before using my client side react app it doesn't and is `undefined`. using `req.headers` I can see `cookies` though. I feel like I can just access `req.headers.cookies` then but what should I do when just running my backend without running my client side app? I do not want to have separate code. Please let me know if I need to clarify what I am saying here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got some extent of your question.
First your node server and your react server won't be running on a same port. So, server cookies won't work like it normally should. You should set domain as well. And if your react server and node server run on that domain and it's domain then they can share the cookie.

Example of sending request to node server with authorization header through axios:

```js
    axios.post("https://<api>.com", {
      headers: {
        Authorization: 'Bearer <your-bearer-token>'
      }
    })
```

postman sends it this way.

Comment: Thank you. Yes I am aware that they do not run on the same server but what I don't get from your answer is that I should set domain. What does this exactly mean and how do I go about achieving this?

Comment: Also the example you gave is something I get I think but doesn't that mean I'd need access to the token on the client side which is not what I want? Or is this after setting the domain that my node and react server will run on?

Comment: What I meant was you can set a domain cookie. For example: if you want them to share cookie then you can host the server on `api.example.com` & your react application on `example.com`. When you return the cookie from your server you can set the cookie domain to `.example.com`  this way when the react application hits your `api.example.com` server, it will have the session cookie. I implemented this on my site https://exampirate.com/ .

Comment: Yes, the I gave you an example of sending your token through authorization headers.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Sorry if I am asking the same question but just making sure I know what you mean by the domain. I am adding this to my `cookieOptions` in my express app `domain: 'http://localhost:3000'`. Not sure if this is how I am suppose to do it?

Comment: no no your domain is `localhost`. Give some tries, it work.

Comment: Is it safe to just send the token in json and set it in local storage in my react app and send it off to my routes the way you showed? When I ask is it okay I mean secure. I tried `domain: localhost` but it didn't work or I should say I can see the token being sent as it was working before but I can't access it through the client

Comment: here, it is when you set the token from your server and set http to true. It means it will only be accessed by server that set it on the client. Client won't access it. Since, you are doing REST API which should be stateless you can go with my earlier approach that is storing in local Storage. Yes, both are not so secure but they are the mostly used approach availble. I think there are service providers for authentication like auth0 etc. but I dont think you need them.